# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 73720019

Tags: java, sockets, error-handling, tcpclient, tcpserver

When random object sent from TCP Server to TCP Client first time everything works fine, but when TCP Server sends again random object this error happens. I have tried with flush() method after sending data, but did not work either. Please, help me...

Sending point of TCP Server

```
try {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);textArea.append("Server started, port : " + PORT + "\n");
    socket = serverSocket.accept();
    textArea.append("Client connected...\n");

    Object object = randomObject();
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    out.writeObject(object);
    textArea.append("Object sent...\n");
    String message = "";

    while(socket.isConnected()){
        in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        message = String.valueOf(in.readObject());
        if(message.equals("Please, send me object again...")){
            textArea.append("Message received : " + message + "\n");
            Object s = randomObject();
            out.writeObject(s);
            textArea.append("Object sent again...\n");
        }
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Problem is here in TCP Client, line breaks at new ObjectInputStream.

```
try {
    socket = new Socket(ADDRESS, PORT);
    System.out.println("Connected...");

    speedLbl.setText("Speed : " + speed + "px");

    while(socket.isConnected()){
        inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

        in = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
        object = in.readObject();

        if(object instanceof Kvadrat){
            kvadrat = (Kvadrat) object;
            koordinatniSistem.add(kvadrat);
            System.out.println(kvadrat.getName());
            label.setText("X : " + kvadrat.getX() + " - Y: " + kvadrat.getY());
        } else if (object instanceof Pravougaonik) {
            pravougaonik = (Pravougaonik) object;
            koordinatniSistem.add(pravougaonik);
            System.out.println(pravougaonik.getName());
            label.setText("X : " + pravougaonik.getX() + " - Y: " + pravougaonik.getY());
        } else if (object instanceof Krug) {
            krug = (Krug) object;
            koordinatniSistem.add(krug);
            System.out.println(krug.getName());
            label.setText("X : " + krug.getX() + " - Y: " + krug.getY());
        }else if (object instanceof Trougao) {
            trougao = (Trougao) object;
            koordinatniSistem.add(trougao);
            System.out.println(trougao.getName());
            label.setText("X : " + trougao.getX() + " - Y: " + trougao.getY());
        } else {
            System.out.println(object.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
        koordinatniSistem.repaint();
    }

} catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the server and not to something else?

Comment: Yes, i'm. Because i am getting random object for the first time, server is sending object, but when am asking randomobject for the second time error occurs

Comment: Ah I overlooked the loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the `ObjectInputStream` in both client and server **once**, **before** the loops. Also, I don't see an `ObjectOutputStream` in your client code, but if there is (judging by the use of an `ObjectInputStream` in the server there should be), it should also be created only **once**.

The problem is that the object input/output streams have a specific protocol, where the creation of the `ObjectOutputStream` sends a "stream header", and the `ObjectInputStream` when created expects to read that header. If you create the object output stream once, but create a new object input stream for each iteration of the loop, then the second creation will fail, because there is no such stream header to read.

Also, to avoid mutual waiting, make sure to create `ObjectOutputStream` *before* `ObjectInputStream`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this was the mistake. I only put reference of the objectinputstream outside while loop and it worked...

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the problem is related to the fact that the client is using a single ObjectInputStream instance to read multiple objects from the server. The ObjectInputStream reads objects in a stream and it might buffer some data internally. When the client sends a message asking the server to send the object again, the server sends a new object, but the client continues to read from the same.To fix this issue, you can create a new ObjectInputStream instance every time the client receives an object from the server. This will ensure that the stream is synchronized with the new object and any buffered data from the previous object is discarded. Here is an updated version of the client code that creates a new ObjectInputStream instance every time an object is received:// Create a new ObjectInputStream instance every time an object is received

```
   `ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
    object = in.readObject();`
```

Comment: It is the exact opposite, the OP is creating a new `ObjectInputStream` every iteration of the loop, and they should only create one per connection.